# Return any / unknown type c++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am attempting to implement [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/) (a json alternative) in c++, and am creating an Iterator class to loop over my byte array, which is separated based on certain headers. So how would the iterator construct and return any type, Eg. `vector<int>`, `map<int, string>` etc. Is `std::any` or `std::variant` the only way to do this? (I don't want to use boost).

My code so far https://github.com/t348575/msgpack

Comment: I'd use `std::variant`. What exactly is your question?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different approaches for what you want to do and each one has its own requirements and drawbacks.

Solution 1: The user knows at compiletime what the serialized data looks like
Just write a template function that takes a type and try do deserialize into it. Check the runtime type info of the binary blob and throw a exception if the type does not match.

Solution 2: User knows the set of types that are possible, std::variant approach:
Make use of the visitor pattern. You can look at the interface of variant for details.

Solution 3: The user has no clue of what types are to come:
You are pretty much out of luck here. You need to make something like std::any which is in its essence a glorified void*.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is designed to be a statically typed language. Hence what you're trying to accomplish (getting a function to return a type determined run-time) is expectedly a struggle :). I'd personally avoid this approach.

std::variant is one solution but it is only going to result in the client probing the content of each return value in a big case statement; or subsequently getting a callback from the visitor pattern. Neither is really the best way to get output from a parser.

I'd have a look at good C++ JSON parsers, see how they solve serialization/deserialization, e.g. https://github.com/nlohmann/json